# Javascript get value and change this value (duplicate value)

Tags: javascript

I want to multiply value from `price_buy_id` with `valCurrecny`:

```
<select class="form-control" name="currency_price_buy" onchange="changePrice(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('valCurrecny'));">
     <option value="1" valcurrecny="1.259200000000">AUD</option>
     <option value="2" valcurrecny="1.572200000000">BGN</option>
     <option value="3" valcurrecny="3.229400000000">BRL</option>
     <option value="4" valcurrecny="1.243400000000">CAD</option>
     <option value="33" valcurrecny="1.000000000000" selected="">USD</option>
     <option value="32" valcurrecny="12.029000000000">ZAR</option>
</select>

<input id="price_buy_id" value="7178.21">
```

And JS code:

```
function changePrice(valCurrecny) {
  var getSelectOption = document.getElementById("price_buy_id").value;
  var multiplication = getSelectOption * valCurrecny;
  // console.log(multiplication);
  document.getElementById("price_buy_id").value = multiplication;
}
```

The problem i swhen I change the value from `currency_price_buy` a few times, then the multiplication result is duplicated. How can I stop duplicating values

Comment: Please include a ***minimal***, complete, ***verifiable*** example. Your example is not minimal as I had to edit out the templating and substitute it for markup, and its not verifiable as I could not [duplicate the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/4q2bhepz/).

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Ok look this: https://jsfiddle.net/4q2bhepz/1/

Comment: taking a wild guess here but perhaps [this is what you wanted](https://jsfiddle.net/0rq6dg26/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the original price somehow. Eg in a data - attribute in the price_buy_id - element:

```
function changePrice(valCurrecny) {
  var getSelectOption = document.getElementById("price_buy_id").data('orig'); 
  var multiplication = getSelectOption * valCurrecny;
  // console.log(multiplication);
  document.getElementById("price_buy_id").value = multiplication;
}
```